# Is there a repeat function in CoffeeScript similar to NumPy?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In NumPy you can easily create an array that repeats values. Like the following.

```
>> print np.arange(3).repeat(2)
[0 0 1 1 2 2]
```

Is there a way to do this in CoffeeScript?

Update:
Following the suggestion that Marius made in his answer, I created a simple function to automate the repeat operation. This is shown for anyone who runs into the same issue in the future.

```
repeat = (arr, repeats) ->
    newArr = for a in arr
        a for [0...repeats]
    return [].concat.apply [], newArr
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested array comprehensions in CoffeeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685449/nested-array-comprehensions-in-coffeescript)

Comment: Note that this code fails for 0 repeats: there is no way to write an array comprehension that has 0 elements. Instead use `i = repeats ; while i-- {` ... `}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly. This is ugly as hell, but works:

```
arr = for a in [0..2]
  a for [0..1]

console.log arr
console.log [].concat.apply [], arr
```

Outputs:

```
[ [ 0, 0 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ] ]
[ 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2 ]
```

The first block creates the nested arrays, and the concat.apply (javascript) method flattens it.

For completeness (see the comments), here's a CS "pretty" version, but notice that it creates another kind of array (it executes the loops in a different order):

```
arr = (a for a in [0..2] for [0..1])

console.log arr
console.log [].concat.apply [], arr
```

outputs:

```
[ [ 0, 1, 2 ], [ 0, 1, 2 ] ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2 ]
```

The last example is not directly comparable to your code, but may be usable anyway depending on what you really are trying to accomplish.

There's lots of things to love about CS, but two things I do hate is 1) ALWAYS having to use whitespace for blocks (no way to make my first example a one-liner), and 2) No object comprehension (not related to this example).

Comment: Bummer. I was hoping there would be something like the `repeat` function. Your solution is good though. I'll just make a function around from it. Thanks!

Comment: If you look at Bergi's link, there's a whole discussion about nested comprehensions and how they differ from Python's. CS has prettier nested comprehensions than what I've shown above, but they differ in ordering from how your Python code works, so I did not demonstrate the CS pretty version. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

CoffeeScript is about the *language* itself. What you're looking for is library support. There isn't anything as comprehensive as NumPy, and it still hasn't a `repeat()` function, but you can at least find a couple of (somewhat) related functions in [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/). [Lemonad](https://github.com/fogus/lemonad) looks promising too for some related tasks.